# Get leave page confirmation after posting comment

Tags: bug, comments

#### Bug:

Every time I leave a SO page (meta or main), if I've left a comment (even after it's already posted), I get the following confirmation:

> This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved

#### To reproduce:

- Comment.
- Refresh page or click a link, or press back, or forward, etc.

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 43.0.4 Linux. Disable all your user scripts, specially SE enchantments/SOAP.

Comment: Just got it again - added example

Comment: I blame https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-optional-features-soof

Comment: Can't reproduce on chrome Version 48.0.2564.97 m (W7)

Comment: BTW, for anyone who is interested, this has been fixed in the stack apps userscript (SOOF) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:  Evidently, the problem was a StackApp (Stack Overflow Optional Features) I was using.  Disabling greasemonkey (or the particular app) fixed it.

I added this as [a GitHub bug](https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Overflow-Optional-Features/issues/46) for them.

**Edit** They also fixed the bug.

Comment: 1 reason why I uninstalled that. It's got a lot of bugs

Comment: @BhargavRao sorry to hear that... I'm the author of that script - if you had any specific problems with it, you can find me in chat (The Tavern @ MSE) or comment on the Stack Apps post, or post an issue on GitHub - I really do try to fix bugs and add new features, so hopefully I'll be able to fix any you have (some may have been fixed since you uninstalled!)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Sry, I got a bit held up today and couldn't meet you. Let's schedule it tomo. BTW the Script was called SAOF rite? (Coz that's the one that I have)

Comment: @BhargavRao the script is named [SOOF](http://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-optional-features-soof).

Comment: Oh damn, I am still running v1.6. The change to SOOF from SAOF was in v1.7. I will reinstall then.

Comment: Yes.  Actually, the dev version currently has fewer bugs than the release version :) That's what I (now) have installed.

Comment: Nice. I am using the release version 1.7 now. It still has the same bugs (reasons why I uninstalled). @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ You gotta be ready for dealing with me ;)

Comment: Check the GitHub [Issues Page](https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Overflow-Optional-Features/issues) to see if it already has your issues.  Also, I was serious when I said the dev version has less bugs.  This bug, for example, is fixed (now) in the dev version.

Comment: @cullub FYI, we had a discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102836/project-trouble-) Do have a look, if you interested. :)