# Scroll bars overlay the review popups

Tags: bug, user-interface

It looks like when code blocks have scroll bars on them, the bars overlay review popups

[image: Exhibit A]

If anything it's more of an annoyance, but it would be nice to get it fixed. I'm using OSX 10.11.2 (El Capitan), and Google Chrome 48.0.2564.97

I tested this on Safari 11601.3.9, and although the bug does not appear, the scroll bars are also hidden when not scrolling, so that may have something to do with why this happens on Chrome (where scroll bars are always visible)

Comment: FWIW this works fine on Windows and Chrome 48.0.2564.103

Comment: I don't recall ever having this problem on my iMac with safari...

Comment: Kinda Similar [Scrollbar always shows over dropdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316078)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: OS X 10.10.5 (14F1605), Chrome 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)

Comment: What! You can move that dialog??? What has the world become!

Comment: Do you have any user scripts enabled, by chance?

Comment: @cullub No, I don't. I'll try reproducing it on another computer that also runs El Capitan, and see what happens

Comment: I was just asking, because I [recently asked a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316023/get-leave-page-confirmation-after-posting-comment) where it was actually a userscript I was using.  I can't test this one out for myself, as I don't have 2K rep.

Comment: This is a Chrome bug - where the rendering of scroll bars is buggy: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571256&q=scrollbars%20layer&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: I think the best part of this bug report is the fact that @Jojodmo move the dialog on a freehand circle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As pointed out](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571256) by [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583), this was actually a bug with Chrome, and not with Stack Overflow. After updating to the newest version of Chrome, this bug no longer appears.

I think I might miss being able to confirm that I am in fact scrolling when code blocks are completely covered[...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke)